# How to use u64 as parameter of function in the browser?

Tags: anchor

One of my method as a `u64` as parameter. I just have to do `new BN(10)` in node.js but it does not work the same in the browser.

```
const val = new BN(10)
const txBuyItem = await program.methods
        .buyItem(val)
        .accounts({
          user: publicKey,
        })
        .rpc();
```

it gives me the error: `TypeError: this._bn.toArrayLike is not a function`

I have tried `new anchor.BN(10).toArrayLike(Buffer, "le", 8)` without success too, it gives me the error: `TypeError: src.toArrayLike is not a function`.

MORE INFO:

In reality I have 2 values, u64 and u32. The doc says to put u32 as `number` in js (doc: https://book.anchor-lang.com/anchor_references/javascript_anchor_types_reference.html). I use anchor 0.26.0 and not 0.24.0 but there is no doc for 0.24.0 from what I see so I just hope it's the same between the 2 versions.

```
import * as anchor from "@project-serum/anchor";

// val1 is a u64 in rust
const val1 = new anchor.BN(10).toArrayLike(Buffer, "le", 8);
// val2 is a u32 in rust
const val2 = new anchor.BN(1).toArrayLike(Buffer, "le", 4);


const txBuyItem = await program.methods
        .buyItem(val1, val2)
        .accounts({
          user: publicKey,
        })
        .rpc();
```

It gives me `TypeError: src.toArrayLike is not a function`. The error is on the line with `const txBuyItem = ....`

Is there something I am missing ?

Comment: can you share more of your code? and the error? in which line it trows the error? are you importing the BN function? how?

Comment: Added a bit more info. I am importing the BN function. I have tried from anchor and from BN.js, I still have the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u32 is just a number, omit the toArrayLike from the BN, like so:

```
// val1 is a u64 in rust
const val1 = new anchor.BN(10);
// val2 is a u32 in rust
const val2 = 1;


const txBuyItem = await program.methods
        .buyItem(val1, val2)
        .accounts({
          user: publicKey,
        })
        .rpc();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the u32 directly, don't cast that as a BN, also in both cases you need to remove the .toArrayLike part